# is there a way to find an adjacent match based on different filters with sqlite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, filtering, dbeaver

I have this database of financial data....I need to do some batch updates to the accounts that certain items are in.

This is double entry stuff, so the transactions have a GUID that matches one to the other (the into account and the out-of account).

I know very little about databases, so maybe this isn't the right way to do this, but my idea was this:

[image]

Notice the memo in green....That's an amazon charge, and all amazon charges have, at the very least, `AMAZON` in their memo.
Also notice that the `tx_guid` is the same for the second entry that has `Amazon` in the memo, as well as the first entry that has nothing in the memo.

The `account_guid` for the second entry is fine...that's the `out-of/credit` account and it's accurate.  The `account_guid` of the first entry is the wrong account, and I want to change it to a different account guid.  I have several entries of this, but the only item I can think of to accurately filter on is the `memo`, which yields a database entry that contains the `tx_guid` of another entry (the first one with nothing in the memo) that needs to have it's `account_guid` entry updated.

How can I find all entries that have `AMAZON` in their memo, collect all the `tx_guid`'s of that search, and then refilter based on those `tx_guid`'s that come through on the aforementioned search?

I'm want a list of all items that have the same `tx_guid`'s as all entries that contain `AMAZON` in their memo, but just the one's that have nothing in their memo....I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, only paste as text.

Comment: You can use a window function `COUNT(CASE WHEN memo LIKE '%AMAZON%' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY tx_guid) AS isAmazon` then filter that to `> 0`

Comment: @Charlieface assuming that i'm trying to change the `account_guid` to `2002`, this command looks like it would work, but it actually updates all `account_guid` 's:
`UPDATE splits SET account_guid = '2002' FROM (SELECT tx_guid, memo, COUNT(CASE WHEN memo LIKE '%AMAZON%' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY tx_guid ) AS isMatch FROM splits) NewTable WHERE (NewTable.isMatch > 0 AND NewTable.memo = '');`

Comment: No there is an implicit cross join there. You should update the subquery directly `UPDATE NewTable SET account_guid = '2002' FROM (......`

Comment: @Charlieface sorry, i just started learning SQL yesterday...I tried this based on how I'm understanding your comment, but I'm obviously misunderstanding it:

`sqlite> UPDATE NewTable SET account_guid = '2002' FROM  (SELECT tx_guid, memo, COUNT(CASE WHEN memo LIKE '%AMAZON%' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY tx_guid ) AS isMatch FROM splits) WHERE (NewTable.isMatch > 0 AND NewTable.memo = '');
Parse error: no such table: NewTable`

Comment: Forgot you were using SQLite, you can't update the derived table. You need to rejoin the derived table back to the original, something like `UPDATE splits SET account_guid = '2002' FROM (SELECT tx_guid, memo, COUNT(CASE WHEN memo LIKE '%AMAZON%' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY tx_guid ) AS isMatch FROM splits) NewTable WHERE NewTable.isMatch > 0 AND NewTable.memo = '' AND NewTable.YourPrimaryKey = splits.YourPrimaryKey;` note the last condition which acts as the join condition.